# MVC does not see Model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Code:

```
    public ActionResult cbpnlNewUpdateConfigs(int id)
    {

        IEnumerable<StorageConfigurationModel> List = (IEnumerable<StorageConfigurationModel>)Session["ConfigurationList"];
        foreach (StorageConfigurationModel configModel in List)
        {
            configModel.
        }
        return PartialView("cbpnlNewUpdateConfigs", new StorageConfigurationModel { });
    }
```

So I want to show in a panel the elements of the model, so I do a partial view sending that info.
But when this method is called, I have to see all my list, find the element I want, and send that info. When I am in the look, I cant see each one of the properties of my model. For example, I have an ID and a Location in my Model, but 'configModel' does not see them.

Why?

CLARIFICATION:
In the main view I have a partial view with a gridview receiving the list of `StorageConfigurationModel` and a partial view with a callbackpanel reveiving just one `StorageConfigurationModel`

and:

```
public class StorageConfigurationModel
{
    public int QueueMonitorConfigurationsID { get; set; }
    public PathType QueueMonitorConfigTypeName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public UnitType QueueMonitorValueTypeName { get; set; }
    public ThresholdType Threshold { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public enum UnitType
{
    MB, GB, TB, Files, Percentage
}
public enum ThresholdType
{
    Upper, Lower
}
public enum PathType
{
    Path
}
```

And the main view:

```
@model IEnumerable<BPM.Website.Models.StorageConfigurationModel>

@Html.Partial("gvConfigurations", Model)


@Html.Partial("cbpnlNewUpdateConfigs", new {id = -1})
```

So when I first load I send a '-1' so the panel loads empty.
But I click edit in the gridview (first partial view) it loads the partialview of the panel with the id clicked, so it needs to find the element in the list and then send it.

Comment: Can you post the `StorageConfigurationModel` class (or the relevant properties in it)?

Comment: Thats what I cant do and I want to

Comment: Why can't you post it?

Comment: oh sorry, I am give me a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the intellisense not working.
Once I build and run it, it works.

No idea why my intellisence didn't work there